# Другие вариации решения задачи?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется следующий массив, как правильно 
Нужно подсчитать сумму элементов count, я делаю это циклом:

```
$arr = [
 [
 'count' => 13,
 'name' => 'Char'
 ],
 [
 'count' => 37,
 'name' => 'Ord'
 ]
];

$count = 0;

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
 $count += $value['count'];
}
```

Существуют ли другие способы сделать это? (кроме цикла)? (я плохо знаком с функциями массивов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот парочка примеров:

Первый вариант с использованием функций `array_sum` + `array_column`:

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, 'count'));
```

Второй вариант с использованием функций `array_sum` + `array_map`:

```
echo array_sum(array_map(function ($r) {
    return $r['count'];
}, $arr));
```

Третий вариант с использованием функции `array_reduce`:

```
echo array_reduce($arr, function(&$res, $item) {
    return $res + $item['count'];
}, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!